# Symfony Pass Data to view

Tags: symfony

My Question is, how I can send Data to my TWIG View in the Symfony Framework.
I guess I will need an action that is passing the data towards it.

Comment: You've already passed your data to the view. We have no way of telling how you intend to render it..

Comment: But how can i worked with my passed Data now ?

Comment: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html

Answer (score 0):

For the Loop, you can check : http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html

But `motos` should be an array, not only a string name

```
 $arrayExample = [ [0] => ['name' => 'Yamaha'], [1] => ['name' => 'Honda'] ]; // motos in twig

{% for data in motos %} 
{{ data.name }} // will display Yamaha // Honda 
{% endfor %}
```

If it's only a string :

```
$data['name'] = 'toto';

{{ myvartwig.name }} // NO LOOP
```

Comment: moto.KEY

I Added a nexample

Comment: I just tryed exact the thing u postet and i still got no output

Comment: Are you using Symfony ? If yes, try to write {{ dump(data) }} in the loop and tell us that you have

Comment: You need to be with the /app_dev.php/ (not working in PROD)

Comment: In you case, if there is only 'teststring', just do this in the view {{ motos.name }}  NO LOOP IF ONLY a String ;)